# htaccess / apache automatically mapping to php files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working with htaccess in a php application.  I want some behavior like this:

1. Send request to mydomain.com/login
2. Have htaccess intercept the request to login and send to index.php?ref=login

However I have that all set up and for some reason it automatically sends the mydomain.com/login request directly to login.php without going through index.php.

I think maybe there is some configuration interfering here?  For reference my .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^news$ /index.php?ref=news [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login$ /index.php?ref=login [NC,L]
```

The news url rewriting works fine and routes it through index.php ... but I have no news.php and suspect that If i did there would be an issue there.

I also apologize if this question is in the wrong spot, I'm not sure if it belongs over at superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) turned on. When you send a request for `/login` to the server, it gets handled by `mod_negotiation` before your `RewriteRule` is correctly applied.

Since `MultiViews` is enabled, and the resource `/login` does not exist, it looks for an existing resource to map it to - In this case, `/login.php`. This is later passed to your `RewriteRule` directives, but since they're looking for the original URL, no match is found, and no rewrite is performed.

Disabling `MultiViews` should fix the problem:

```
Options -MultiViews
```